# Why an IPhone XS Max appears here? (Do not own an iphone XS max nor there is one in proximity)

Tags: console

This is what I see in `Console` app.

[image]

However I did not see this item in the morning (about two hours ago)

The MacBookPro I am working on is a second hand unit.

My question: how did it make its way to console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entry is added by an instance of `Simulator` (part of XCode for testing purpose)